# Mouseover not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a simple menu which will show up menu items when clicking on menu
and will hide when mouseout from menuitem.

http://jsfiddle.net/MMHVv/3/

In firefox this does not work,
the `menuItem` gets hidden when mouseover

in chrome it works properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generally avoid inline javascript, see: 
http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

You should use the mouseover and mouseout functions instead:
http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

```
$(function() {
   $('#menu').mouseover(function() {
       $('#TestMenu').show();
   }).mouseout(function(){
    $('#TestMenu').hide();
   });;
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/MMHVv/16/

The TestMenu should also be placed inside the first div, so the mouseover is also effective when you hover over the TestMenu.

Answer (score 0):

I had seen your code..

i dont know what went wrong with the `mousemove` event in firefox

if you replace `mousemove` with `mouseover` it works fine..

```
onmouseover="return ShowMenu($(this));"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this just with your structure but one edit [*`removed the id for the menuitems`*]:

```
$(function () {
  $('.menu').on({
    mouseover: function () {
        $('.menuItem').slideUp();
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
  });
  $('.menuItem').on({
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

**check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMHVv/19/)**